# add click function condition to current button function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like the below function to fire ONLY if element id `#submit` is clicked. I was creating another button (back button) and for some reason after my back button was fired, the below code ran regardless... so I need to wrap the below in another condition (only ig #submit is clicked)

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    var complete = function(){
          $('.form-container').find('header').hide();
          $(form).fadeOut(function(){
          $('#thanks').fadeIn();
        });
    };
```

here is the code for the back button -- it runs onclick as supposed to, BUT afterward the 'submit' function above runs. I need the submit above to ONLY run with the submit click not the back click.

```
//* back button */

document.getElementById('back').addEventListener('click', function () {
    jQuery('.step1').show();
    jQuery('submit3').hide();
    jQuery('#privacyalert').hide();
    jQuery('.step2').hide();
    jQuery('.step3').hide();
    jQuery('#thanks').hide();
    jQuery('#back').hide();

},  false);
```

Comment: I'm guessing here, but is `back` a `<button>` tag with no type attribute specified, and is also within your `<form>`?  If so, it will default to `type="submit"` and submit your form.  Set it to `type="button"`.  @Radio Just looked at your dupe - it is indeed a duplicate if the OP can confirm this... though it sounds very likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the back button type to `type="button"`. The default is `type="submit"` so that is most likely triggering it your submitHandler.

Answer (score 1):

Here it goes

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
var complete = function(){
              $('.form-container').find('header').hide();
              $(form).fadeOut(function(){
              $('#thanks').fadeIn();
            });
});
```